# What is the audio voltage of an android phone?

Tags: voltage, audio, android

For a project I am currently working on, I need to use the audio output of an android device. Is there a standard max voltage?

Comment: What do you want to drive? A high impedance electronic circuit or are you hoping to run a motor directly from it as many have asked before? Maximum voltage doesn't tell you the whole story. You may have high voltage but low current capability and, therefore, very low power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really a standard, it depends on exactly what headphone amplifier the phone uses. The closest thing is the -10dBV (.9VPP) consumer line level output, but I doubt most phones have the actual output level calibrated to that standard. It's more than likely that they tested it by plugging the phone into a couple of AV receivers and found that it got "loud enough" with some volume adjustments.

In any case, the headphone amplifier's job is to push current through a load which might have a wide range of impedances. This means that the maximum output voltage into a high-Z load isn't that important for the intended application, and is sometimes omitted from the datasheet. Your best bet is to take apart or look at disassembled photos of various phones, figure out what headphone amp they are using, and go from there. For example, the [TI TPA6166A2](http://www.ti.com/product/tpa6166a2) quotes:

VOUT,Max Max line output voltage RL = 10 kΩ 1 VRMS

But many other devices omit this spec. You can probably estimate it from looking at the power output and using the average power equation with the quoted load.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into this before, and it seems that voltage outputs from audio devices can vary wildly, and no real standard exists for consumer devices. I've also read about Automatic Gain Control (AGC), and you might look into that, since it appears to amplify a signal to a set maximum gain, so you know the output voltage maximum. See [this](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/MAX9814.pdf) datasheet for an example of one such chip.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be standardized across headsets for Android. There's a 150mV peak drive at 32ohms.
https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/specification.html

Comment: IDK why this was down voted, (maybe because of dead link?) but I up voted it to even it out, as it's the correct answer. Here is the fresh link, btw. https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/jack-headset-spec